# Route only certain IP range with VPN connection

Tags: linux, networking, macos, vpn, routing

We are using `FortiClient` to connect to one of our client's VPN. Unfortunately, `FortiClient` is routing **all the traffic over VPN as default**.

We have found a way around it, for Linux. After connecting with VPN we run:

```
sudo route del default ppp0
sudo route add -net 172.20.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev ppp0
```

And now, only the addresses starting with `172.20.x.x` are resolved over VPN connection.

Now, I am using `FortiClient 5.4` on `Mac OS X 10.11.6` and I am trying to remake the above to work on `Mac OS X`. Basically I have problems even with the first step. I have tried:

```
sudo route delete -net default -ifp ppp0
```

But the routing still does not work expected. Easily to test, because there is no Internet connection behind the VPN - I can not browse/ping any website :-).

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help!

Comment: See the script in [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/728707/18736).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/728702/how-to-get-forticlient-working-in-osx-el-capitan/728707#728707) to help me out and it turned out I needed one extra command.

Basically the working solution for `Mac OS X 10.11.6` goes as follows:

```
sudo route delete -net default -interface ppp0
sudo route add -net 0.0.0.0 -interface en0
sudo route add -net 172.20.0.0 -netmask 255.255.0.0 -interface ppp0
```

Which basically means:

1. Delete default route on interface `ppp0` which was set by `FortiClient`
2. Add default route for every IP on your default interface (for me `en0`)
3. Route the specific IP range through `ppp0` (FortiClient) interface.

`Linux` equivalent, as mentioned in the question, is:

```
sudo route del default ppp0
sudo route add -net 172.20.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev ppp0
```

So you actually skip the step #2.

Not that hard in the end.