# Route only certain traffic through F5 VPN

Tags: vpn, ip

I need to use F5 VPN to enable communications to access a certain server at our university.
Since using this VPN all the time is not an option due to other hassles brought by it, I thought to only route traffic to this certain sever-IP / domain name through F5.

Is this possible? I'm using the F5 client version 2.x on OSX.

I've already tried the solution from [Route only certain IP range with VPN connection](https://superuser.com/questions/1108277/route-only-certain-ip-range-with-vpn-connection) but "ppp0" seems undefined.

When I'm connected to VPN, I see "utun5" being created as a connection.

```
utun5: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1391
 options=6463<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
 inet xxxxxx --> xxxxxx netmask 0xffffffff
 inet6 xxxxxx prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x14
 inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
 nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```